# R: mutate over multiple columns to create a new column

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I'm trying to create a new column based on values of other columns.

Here is a dataset that is similar to what I'm working on. 
I have three variables, Test1, Test2, Test3. 
I am trying to create a new variable that is 1 if any of the Test variables are
either DF60, DF61, DF63 or DF64 or 0 otherwise.

```
Test1<-c("DF64", "DF63", "DF89", "DF30", "DF70")
Test2<-c("DF61", "DF25", "DF00", "DF30", "DF99")
Test3<-c("DF80", "DF63", "DF60", "DF63", "DF70")
Test<-data.frame(Test1, Test2, Test3)
```

I have many ifelse statements at the moment and am looking for a code that can
loop over the multiple Test variables while allowing multiple values to be looked up.

After looking through some similar threads, I tried mutate_at but I don't think that is the right way.

```
Test2<- Test %>%
mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Test")), funs(Test=ifelse("DF60" | "DF61" | 
"DF62" | "DF63", 1, 0)))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Test2<- Test %>%
dplyr::select(starts_with("Test"))%>%
mutate_all(function(x){x %in% c("DF60","DF61","DF62","DF63")})%>%
mutate(out = ifelse(rowSums(.)<1,0,1))
```

**Adjustment after comment**

If you want to keep other columns, mutate_at, as is proposed by yutannihilation, is far better. The problem then becomes doing the rowsums in mutate on a selection of the columns. No idea if the next thing is best practice, but it works (reworked an answer on a previous question of mine: [dplyr mutate on column subset (one function on all these columns combined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472890/dplyr-mutate-on-column-subset-one-function-on-all-these-columns-combined))

```
library(tidyverse)
library(anomalyDetection)

Test1<-c("DF64", "DF63", "DF89", "DF30", "DF70")
Test2<-c("DF61", "DF25", "DF00", "DF30", "DF99")
Test3<-c("DF80", "DF63", "DF60", "DF63", "DF70")
Test<-data.frame(Test1, Test2, Test3)

Test$ExtraCol<-LETTERS[1:5]


Test2<- Test %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Test")),funs(bin=.%in% c("DF60","DF61","DF62","DF63")))%>%
  split(.,1<10)%>%
  map_df(~mutate(.,out=rowSums(.[paste0("Test",1:3,"_bin")])>0))


  Test1 Test2 Test3 ExtraCol Test1_bin Test2_bin Test3_bin   out
   DF64  DF61  DF80        A     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE  TRUE
   DF63  DF25  DF63        B      TRUE     FALSE      TRUE  TRUE
   DF89  DF00  DF60        C     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE  TRUE
   DF30  DF30  DF63        D     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE  TRUE
   DF70  DF99  DF70        E     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to keep all the original variables (there are other variables in addition to Test1, Test2, Test3)?  I need to create multiple variables based on the same Test1, Test2, Tes3 variables so would like to not have them changed.

Comment: split splits the df into a list of df's based on the argument. The following map_df applies the argument on each of those df's and binds them back into one df. In this case I didn't want a list of different df's, but just a list of one df (the whole df). That's why I split based on an argument that's always true (not sure if it's necessary, you could try without. This answer is based on a previous question of mine on stackoverflow. If you follow the link, you will see where the split comes from)

Answer (score 1):

While Dries's answer is nice enough, let me add some explanation about `funs()`.

`funs()` takes pairs of suffix and expression. For example, if you specify `suffix1` and `suffix2`, you will get new columns named `Test1_suffix1`, `Test1_suffix2`, `Test2_suffix1`, `Test2_suffix2` and so on:

```r
funs(suffix1 = ..., suffix2 = ...)
```

Second, you need `.` to represent a column vector. So, the correct version of your `ifelse(...)` should be like:

```r
Test %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Test")),
            funs(bin = ifelse(. == "DF60" | . == "DF61" | . == "DF62" | . == "DF63", 1, 0)))
#>   Test1 Test2 Test3 Test1_bin Test2_bin Test3_bin
#> 1  DF64  DF61  DF80         0         1         0
#> 2  DF63  DF25  DF63         1         0         1
#> 3  DF89  DF00  DF60         0         0         1
#> 4  DF30  DF30  DF63         0         0         1
#> 5  DF70  DF99  DF70         0         0         0
```

Apparently, `%in%` is better than sequence of `|`.

```r
Test %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Test")),
            funs(bin = ifelse(. %in% c("DF60", "DF61", "DF62", "DF63"), 1, 0)))
#>   Test1 Test2 Test3 Test1_bin Test2_bin Test3_bin
#> 1  DF64  DF61  DF80         0         1         0
#> 2  DF63  DF25  DF63         1         0         1
#> 3  DF89  DF00  DF60         0         0         1
#> 4  DF30  DF30  DF63         0         0         1
#> 5  DF70  DF99  DF70         0         0         0
```

If you just want to filter, you can use `filter_at()`.

```r
Test %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Test")),
            any_vars(. %in% c("DF60", "DF61", "DF62", "DF63")))
#>   Test1 Test2 Test3
#> 1  DF64  DF61  DF80
#> 2  DF63  DF25  DF63
#> 3  DF89  DF00  DF60
#> 4  DF30  DF30  DF63
```